# why dmaster demo site refused to connect in locally?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I have installed CiviCRM buildkit form https://github.com/michaelmcandrew/civicrm-buildkit-docker. I have installed a stable release 0.9.0 and  created the dmaster demo site using `docker-compose exec -u buildkit civicrm civibuild create dmaster` command. But when i go to the http://dmaster.localhost:7979/ it says '`dmaster.localhost refused to connect`'. But phpmyadmin and MailDev working properly. I'll appreciate if someone could help me to resolve the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Just for clarity, often when we refer to 'dmaster demo' we mean https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/  But in this case you are talking about a local site.

Comment: @Aidan yeah local site. Do you have any idea it's not working?

Comment: Sorry, no - I have not used the docker image.

Comment: okay thank you!